# How to validate Regular Expression for time in 24 Hr format in Flex 4.5?

Tags: regex, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

```
var regex1:RegExp=/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)(?i:)(am|pm)/;      
 var fo:String = "12:00 AM";  
 var ismatched:Boolean = regex1.test(fo);  
 trace(ismatched);
```

The result it print on console  is false.

I want to Regexp to ignore space between minutes and AM and PM.

I want to validate time For format HH:MM AM/PM

- Regular Expression must validate Format like "12:00 AM","12:10 am","11:10am","11:10pm","11:15PM".
- Regular expression must written true for each one of them.
- It must ignore spaces before AM,PM for ex:"11:10 AM" .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about flex but in Java the case-insensitive flag must be without the colon, i.e. `(?i)` instead of `(?i:)`

Oh and the whitespace group needs a quantifier: `(\\s*)` or `(\\s?)` instead of `(\\s)`, depending on how many spaces you want to ignore.

Btw, do you need all those groups to be capturing?

Another side note: when fixed according the errors I mentioned above your expression would still allow for times like `23:00 AM`, so you might want to extend your expression to allow `[0]?[0-9]|1[0-2]` only, when AM or PM are expected.

**Update**: according to the flex documentation it seems that your am/pm query should look like this: `(?i:(am|pm))` (the doc says `(?option:expression)`.

Additionally I don't know whether you need to escape the backslash in Flex or not, so please check. If you don't have to escape it, `(\\s?)` would match "a backslash optionally followed by the letter s" instead of optional whitespace.

Comment: yes,thomas I need all these grouping to be captured Thanks for your suggestion .I will try this

Comment: yes write thomas it should be in 12 hr format.But its not working in Adobe flex.thats how adobe flex patterns are              http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html

Comment: @user1942215 what expression did you use and what test string? If you used the one in your comment to arco's answer, note that checking times with leading zeros might return false if the _entire_ string must match (again I don't know flex but in Java `String#matches(...)` requires the expression to match everything in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The test for your white space must be optional if you need to match both "11:10am" and "12:00 AM", you need to change \s to \s?

Comment: Arco444:I need in such a way that if user enter space between minutes and Am/pm then it should return true and if not included then it should written true

Comment: This is exactly what I'm saying, you need to make the test for the white space optional by adding the '?' Thomas has suggested the same thing.

Comment: Arc0:now how its look like (1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s?)(?i)(am|pm) var fo:String = "12:00 AM"  but its still return false .Is am i going wrong some where

Comment: That looks correct to me. I'm not sure about the syntax for a regex in flex (in particular the placement of the `(?i)`), but I've tested this as you have it above and it works for both "12:00AM" and "12:00 AM"

Answer (score 0):

Following expression is working for the required validation both with AM/PM or without them.

```
/(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\s)?(?i)(am|pm)?/
```